# Could anyone help me to find an example of poping up info window on Google map when mouse moves event?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was wondering if there is any example of javascript that I could refer to: I built a Google map javascript with Oracle APEX. In this application, I need to make my javascript code working as this way, whenever my mouse moves across a pin icon on the Google map, the info window pops up, and when mouse moves away, the info window disappears. I am not familiar to javascript, I wish I could know which term I could use to search in forums to find examples. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You are not familiar with JavaScript? How did you create the Google Map? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple